# Calculate Residue of $1/(z^2+1)$ at $z = i$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Really simple I want to check the Residue for $f(z) = \dfrac{1}{z^2+1}$. I receive 2 different values probably due to one stupid miscalculation.

First one is classic: $\displaystyle\mathrm{Res(f(z), z =i) = \lim_{z\to i}}\dfrac{1}{(z-i)\,(z+i)}\,(z-i) = \dfrac{1}{2\,i}$

Second one is overcomplicated, using the formula for higher poles:

$\displaystyle \mathrm{Res}(f(z),z = i) = \lim_{z \to i} f'(z)\cdot(z-i)^2 = \lim_{z \to i} \dfrac{-2\,z}{(z-i)^2\,(z+i)^2}\,(z-i)^2 = -\dfrac{1}{2\,i} \quad \textsf{Why that sign error?}$

Comment: $\lim_{z \to i} \frac{-2z}{(z+i)^2} = \frac{-2i}{(2i)^2} = \frac{-2i}{-4}$

Comment: I'd suggest parentheses in the title.  You ask about "the Residue" of a rational function with two poles.  It is possible for a function to have different residues at different singularities, so please edit to reflect where you want to find a residue.

Comment: @ConnorHarris but isn't that $\dfrac{2\,i}{4} = \dfrac{2\,i\,i}{4\,i} = -\dfrac{1}{2\,i}$?

Comment: @Leon Yes, you're right. I think your arithmetic is correct. But I'm not sure that you can use the formula for order-2 poles to find the residue at an order-1 pole.

Comment: Oh, I thought $+i$ is  a second order pole, since $i^2+1 = 0$, but factorising it it's indeed first order. I guess that's the thing with complex number always coming in pairs

Comment: @Leon actually, the second-order poles formula works fine - it's just that you have the formula wrong: you want $\lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{d}{dz} ((z-z_0)^2 f(z))$, not $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)^2 \frac{d}{dz} f(z)$.

Comment: The idea behind the formula is that (taking $z_0 = 0$ for convenience) if you have a Laurent series $\frac{c_{-n}}{z^n} + \frac{c_{-n+1}}z^{n-1} + \cdots + \frac{c_{-1}}{z} + c_0 + c_1z + c_2z^2$, then first you multiply by $z^n$ to give all of the terms non-negative exponents, then you take $n-1$ derivatives to get rid of the terms from $c_{-n}$ through $c_{-2}$ and then leave $c_{-1}$ in the constant term.

Comment: Huge Reminder, thanks. I thought it comes from Cauchy integral formula: $\displaystyle f^{k}(z) = \dfrac{k!}{2\,\pi\,i}\,\int \dfrac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{k+1}}\,\mathrm{d\zeta}$ solving for $f(\zeta)$ and taking the limit, but it seems slightly more complicated.